# what does class_initialize() do?

Tags: inheritance, createjs

I am trying to learn how to create createjs objects.

I am investigating createjs/tutorials/Inheritance/demo.html and Button.js

```
(function() {
var Button = function(label, color) {
  this.initialize(label, color);
}
var p = Button.prototype = new createjs.Container(); // inherit from Container

p.label;
p.background;
p.count = 0;

*p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;*
Button.prototype.initialize = function (label, color) {

    *this.Container_initialize();*

    this.label = label;
    if (!color) { color = "#CCC"; }

    var text = new createjs.Text(label, "20px Arial", "#000");
    text.textBaseline = "top";
    text.textAlign = "center";

    var width = text.getMeasuredWidth()+30;
    var height = text.getMeasuredHeight()+20;

    this.background = new createjs.Shape();
    this.background.graphics.beginFill(color).drawRoundRect(0,0,width,height,10);

    text.x = width/2;
    text.y = 10;

    this.addChild(this.background,text); 
    this.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);  
    this.addEventListener("tick", this.handleTick);
} 

p.handleClick = function (event) {    
    var target = event.target;
    alert("You clicked on a button: "+target.label);
} 

p.handleTick = function(event) {       
    p.alpha = Math.cos(p.count++*0.1)*0.4+0.6;
}

window.Button = Button;
}());
```

there is a self calling function this.Container_initialize();
I tried to comment it out, which made the code not working.
Can someone explain what does the function Container_initialize do?
Is that an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an infinite loop, what is happening is that you are making a 'copy' (really just a new reference) of the old initialize.

```
p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;
```

Here, `p.initialize` is the same as `createjs.Container.prototype.initialize`.
When you write:

```
Button.prototype.initialize = function(...) {
```

You are overriding the `Container.prototype.initialize`, but since you saved it in the `Container_initialize` you can still call it.

As for what the functions does, that's a matter of reading the source code, it probably sets up whatever internal stuff is needed by the container object. That's why you can't not call it.